# Java - Removing the panel where the button is located

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, removechild

Is it possible that when i click the button that is located in a certain panel, that panel will be removed?

like

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==removebutton)
        System.out.println("ok");
    removebutton.getRootPane().remove(cartpanel);

}
```

i'M Trying to make a shopping cart wherein when the customer view the cart, he will see the items located in a panel that have a remove button. Then when he clicks that button, the panel will be removed.

my code above is not doing the expected output, but is there any method that should be used with that?

[panel http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62021435/Untitled.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62021435/Untitled.png)

Comment: From you picture, I'd recommend using a `JTable` instead, see [How to use JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Component#getParent` to get a reference to the parent container.  You would then need to get the `Container`'s parent and remove the button's container from it...

```
Container myParent = removebutton.getParent();
Container parent = myParent.getParent();
parent.remove(myParent);
```

Comment: is the myParent there, the panel where the button is located. and the parent is the panel where everything is located?

Comment: `myParent` is the container where `removebutton` lives, `parent` is where `myParent` lives. In order to remove the buttons container, we need a reference to the containers parent so we can ask it to remove the buttons container :P